# Oracle SQL (Oracle11g) - select statement where date equal to another select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following script that shows the last 11 months from the sysdate...

```
select * from (
select level-1 as num, 
to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),- (level-1)),'MM')||'-'||to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),- (level-1)),'YYYY') as dte
from dual
connect by level <= 12
)
pivot  (
max(dte) as "DATE"
for num in (0 as "CURRENT", 1 as "1", 2 as "2", 3 as "3", 4 as "4", 5 as "5",6 as "6",7 as "7",8 as "8",9 as "9",10 as "10", 11 as "11"))
```

[image]

I want to create a table that shows delivery qty where the delivery date ('MM-YYYY') equals the date generated from the above script.

I get the delivery qty and delivery date from the following

```
select dp.catnr,
       nvl(sum(dp.del_qty),0) del_qty
  from bds_dhead@sid_to_cdsuk dh, 
       bds_dline@sid_to_cdsuk dp 
 where dp.dhead_no = dh.dhead_no 
   and dh.d_status = '9' 
   and dp.article_no = 9||'2EDVD0007' 
   and to_char(trunc(dh.actshpdate),'MM')||'-'||to_char(trunc(dh.actshpdate),'YYYY') = = --this is where I would like to match the result of the above script
       group by dp.catnr
```

The results would look something like...

[image]

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Thanks, SMORF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with date_series as (
  select add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'), 1 - lvl) start_date, 
         add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'), 2-lvl) - 1/24/60/60 end_date
  from (select level lvl from dual connect by level <= 12)
),
your_table as (
  select 'catnr1' catnr, 100500 del_qty, sysdate actshpdate from dual
  union all select 'catnr1' catnr, 10 del_qty, sysdate-30 actshpdate from dual
  union all select 'catnr2' catnr, 15 del_qty, sysdate-60 actshpdate from dual
),
subquery as (
select to_char(ds.start_date, 'MM-YYYY') dte, t.catnr, sum(nvl(t.del_qty, 0)) del_qty 
from date_series ds left join your_table t 
     on (t.actshpdate between ds.start_date and ds.end_date)
group by to_char(ds.start_date, 'MM-YYYY'), t.catnr     
)     
select * from subquery pivot (sum(del_qty) s for dte in ('11-2013' d1, '12-2013' d2, '08-2014' d10, '09-2014' d11, '10-2014' d12))
where catnr is not null;
```